# Angular 2: Azure AD login redirect URI

Tags: typescript, angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on using Azure AD to login into an Angular 2 app. The following Github link shows an easy way to login without using any auth libraries.

[Log in via Microsoft Graph using Typescript and Angular 2](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/angular2-connect-rest-sample://)

It works well, however, in the example, it redirects right back to the main screen where the login process was initiated from. I'm trying to figure out how to redirect back to a different localhost view, but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

I can get a redirect to https://www.google.com to work. You can do this by altering the code found in /src/authHelper/authHelper.ts to use your redirect URL of choice, instead of reverting back to window.location.href:

```
    login() {
    //redirect to get id_token
    window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + SvcConsts.TENTANT_ID + 
        "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + SvcConsts.CLIENT_ID + 
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent('HTTPS://WWW.GOOGLE.COM') + 
        "&state=SomeState&nonce=SomeNonce";
}
```

This also requires you to set the Reply URL in your Azure Active Directory to https://www.google.com. This can be found at by selecting your Azure AD, then clicking the application under that AD, and then setting the Reply URL under the Configure tab on the old Azure portal.

--HOWEVER--

I cannot get this to work for a plain ol' made-from-scratch view. Every time I try to replace https://www.google.com with something like https://localhost:8080/redirect or something, I get an error in the browser saying "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" or something along those lines.

Right now I have this in Azure AD as the Reply URL for my web app:

[image]

My updated login code (I am using the SvcConsts locally, referenced with this.):

```
    login() {
    console.log("Logging in!");

    //redirect to get id_token
    window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + this.TENTANT_ID + 
        "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + this.CLIENT_ID + 
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent('https://localhost:8080/#/redirect') + 
        "&state=SomeState&nonce=SomeNonce";
}
```

...and a router/routes configured in my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from '../authentication/authentication.component';
import { AuthRedirectComponent } from '../authRedirect/authRedirect.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';

import '../style/styles.less';

@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   template:
   `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <em>some content</em>
    <app-login></app-login>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   `,
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, AuthenticationComponent],
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

@Routes([
    { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/redirect', component: AuthRedirectComponent }
])

export class AppComponent {
    title: string = "App Component Title";

}
```

Has anyone gotten around this? I need to keep my Azure AD for authentication, so I can't use local accounts or any other libraries like Auth0. I also must stick to localhost views now since I don't have deployment figured out.

Thanks

Comment: Azure AD doesn't support redirect uris with fragments (#) in them. The other thing (might be obvious but have to call it out just in case) is to make sure you actually have IIS/Node/Apache or something running on localhost:8080. Can you confirm that you can actually navigate to localhost:8080 on your browser?

Comment: @Saca I've got a server started on localhost:8080 with Webpack. That's how I'm starting my session. I've got a button that you click that takes you to the Azure login page...I just want to be sent to a different view pending successful authentication.

Comment: @supbro did you ever get this working? I am having a similar issue but with the QS that comes baclk. The code is looking for id_token in the QS, but it is not being built properly

Answer (score 0):

for this you set redirect url as **http://localhost:8080**.

```
login() {
    //redirect to get id_token
    window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + SvcConsts.TENTANT_ID + 
        "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + SvcConsts.CLIENT_ID + 
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:8080') + 
        "&state=YOUR_ROUTE&nonce=SomeNonce&response_mode=query";
}
```

and set your specific route in state value so when auth success it redirect like 
http://localhost:8080/?state=YOUR_ROUTE&id_token=YOUR_TOKEN.
After success redirection get data from url in your main app.component.ts file like

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {

                let token = params['id_token'];
        //save token 
                if(typeof token !="undefined"){
                window.localStorage.setItem('authToken',token);
                  let route = JSON.parse(params['state']);
                 window.location.href =route;
                }
            });
    }
```