# Ionic 5 msal Authentication failed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, ionic5, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to implement Microsoft SSO authentication in ionic 5.

Undefine occurs in the console when the code below is executed. Which part is the problem?

```
login(){
let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');

authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', 'clientID', 'http://localhost:8200')
  .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
    console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
    console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
  })
  .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
```

}

error =>
[image]

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ms-adal/

Answer (score 0):

```
const browser = this_.iab.create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id +
              "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + client_id
              +"&state=SomeState&nonce=SomeNonce"
              , '_blank', 'clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,toolbarposition=top,hidenavigationbuttons=yes,toolbarcolor=#0072bb')
            browser.on("loadstart").subscribe(event => {
```

IAB is inappbrowser. Msal we had also tried to use when we needed this type of authentication for azure AD b2c. Similarly you have to do for your case.

There is enterprise level plugin available which cost around 8 lakhs INR.
So this is the work around. Tenant id and client id you will get when you register your app under applications in azure account.

So once the login is successful that load listener will listen to pages which IAB is visiting. And if found occurrence of #token_id(after sucesfull login).

Automatically the iab will close and ionic app page will resume or you can put some new route entry in that event listener.

May be for your case the base url might change. So try first visiting chrome with the url which opens your case login. And accordingly change.

MAKE IT WORK USING IAB AND NOT MSAL

Comment: I think the url link is wrong, do you have a tutorial? error message => "lang":"en","value":"Request url was invalid. The request should be like \/tenantdomainname\/Entity or \/$metadata. Tenant domain name can be any of the verified, unverified domain names or context id.

Comment: See that is what i am saying. We have used azure ad b2c login. Tenant id and client id you need to create under applications in your azure account. You cannot use the link directly. Tanant id and client is are basically variables. That way you will have your own.
Microsoft SSO authentication check how you register apps in azure . 
You first register your azure ad b2c application. It will show you tenant id and client id.
That you insert there. 

You must get the token in the url using this. You can try on chrome first and then try similar way on ionic app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211141/angular-2-azure-ad-login-redirect-uri

This was reference stack overflow link we used to achieve our goal.

Comment: How do I enter the redirect url to run the Android and iOS apps at the same time? Can you help?

Comment: For android and iOS both the url will be same. You do not need to enter the redirect URL.
browser.on("loadstart").subscribe(event => {
Keep listening to that loadstart event. You will consoles on both android and iOS in debug mode every time you IAB visits a new page. After login in IAB the azure will send your defined url with #id_token . What you need to do now is in loadstart, if IAB url contains that '#id_token'. You close the IAB and redirect back to app using.

Comment: if (event.url.includes('#id_token')) { 
    var s1=token.substring(event.url.indexOf("#") + 10)
    var azure_token = atob(s1.split(".")[1])
you ll see object
browser.close();   will close IAB

Comment: Can I set the url as appid?

Comment: I get the following error: AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

Comment: Do not add that as redirect url. Check my solution i have not added that redirect url see.
I think you are adding it before loadstart event. Where do you get that error though?
I just guessed what can be wrong.
Remember to place # in that loadstart listener

Comment: What you do is first use chrome to login your azure using tenant and client id.
See after login what azure sends in the url. It will be sending a token with some string.
Accordingly you check and do.

Comment: If you don't set the redirect address, you'll get an error stating that the client and tenant id could not be found.  AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'tenantid' was not found in the directory 'clientid'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: But I registered the app in azure ad.

Comment: const browser = this.iab.create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" +this.tenant_id +
      "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + this.client_id +
      +"&state=SomeState&nonce=SomeNonce"
      , '_blank', 'clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,toolbarposition=top,hidenavigationbuttons=yes,toolbarcolor=#0072bb')
    browser.on("loadstart").subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    });

Comment: url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + this.tenant_id +
      "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + this.client_id +
      "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent( 'http://localhost:8200') +
      "&state=YOUR_ROUTE&nonce=SomeNonce&response_mode=query";

Comment: When redirecting to localhost8200 as above, it returns to 8200 and the following error occurs in the address bar. http://localhost:8200/?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=AADSTS700054%3a+response_type+%27id_token%27+is+not+enabled+for+the+application.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+bb8a455b-41cf-4f2e-8198-383ed5b89400%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+2145506a-139a-4609-b86e-68c2d6d2d5fd%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2021-07-16+06%3a13%3a38Z&error_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2ferror%3fcode%3d700054&state=YOUR_ROUTE#

Comment: Do not use redirecturl . I have mentioned before also many times. Check previous comments to get it work using loadstart

Comment: remove that redirect url from that login.microsoft

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436611/redirect-url-error-on-ms-login-in-ionic-5  Could you please look at what I wrote again?