# redirect url error on ms login in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, azure-application-insights, ionic5

I am trying to implement microsoft login using ionic5.

It goes to the login page, but after logging in, the following error appears.

Please help me what to do in this case.

[image]

```
login(){
const url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + this.tenant_id +
  "/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=" + this.client_id + "&state=SomeState&nonce=SomeNonce";

//here we create iab browser for login page.
const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', {
  location: 'no',
  zoom: 'no',
  hardwareback: 'no',
  clearcache: 'yes'
});

browser.on("loadstart").subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
  //this.splashScreen.show();
});

browser.on("loadstop").subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);

  this.splashScreen.hide();
  browser.show();
});

browser.on("loaderror").subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
  /*
  var result = event.url.split("code=");
  console.log("Authentication result", result);

  window["AuthResult"] = result[1].split('&')[0];

  localStorage.setItem('AuthCode', window["AuthResult"]);
  browser.close();
  */
});
```

}

After modifying the code, the following error is called.

[image]

Comment: detect url change: `browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('loadStory', res);
      if (res.url == 'xyz.com') {
        browser.close();
      }
    }, err => {
      console.error(err);
    });`

Comment: Could you take a look at my question again? I modified the code as you said. But I still get the error.

Comment: are you using capacitor? if yes please check cleartext pemissons,

Answer (score 0):

Print the url in console and copy and paste in chrome. If chrome is able to open the url. Than the problem is your app is not able to make http calls.
Step 1: try opening url in chrome. If it opens there. App it should.
Step 2: may be instead of loading your url . Load say
https://www.google.com/ in app . If that also fails than your sure app is unable to load the url.
Step3: Allow the app to communicate to external http calls. And your login url will start working.  As I said first make Google.com  work on app.

Comment: https://sj.qq.com/myapp/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsIVVRQXUv=SomeState&session_state=b1fe79f5-9e25-475f-ab5a-157c9a6b8d7b

Comment: When login is complete, the above url is returned. Are you returning the url because you didn't set the redirect url? I don't know if the idtoken in the url is a normal token, and I don't know where to store the information if the login is successful.

Comment: Anyway, I think the redirect address should be specified.

Comment: store in localstorage and use it when you want